# Gesture recognizer in iOS UiTableViewCell's sub view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I tried to add gesture recognizer in UITableViewCell's sub view. That doesn't seem to work. If add one for the cell it's working. Any idea why?

```
@objc public class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
...
    @objc private let subView = createSubView()
...
    @objc public override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
       
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:)))
        subView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        subView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addSubview(subView)
    }
    
    @objc private func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // never happen
        return
    }
```

The reason for this is to detect complex gesture inside a view so table view's default delegate or cell's gesture handler is not enough.

Comment: All subviews should be added to the cell's `contentView`, not to the cell itself: `contentView.addSubview(subView)`

Comment: Excellent! That solved the issue.